# checkbox filter in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm trying to learn more about the checkbox functions in android. I want to display the values of the checked Checkboxes in TextView. In my code, it shows all the checkboxes either true(if checked) or false (if not checked) but I only want to print those checkboxes which are checked and exclude those are unchecked. I tried using "if, else if" but its not working. Any help will be really appreciated.

MainActivity:

```
public class Demo extends Activity {

    private CheckBox linux, macos, windows;
    private Button button;
    private EditText ed1, ed2;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        linux = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        macos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        windows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("Android check : ").append(linux.isChecked());
                result.append("\nWindows OS check : ").append(macos.isChecked());
                result.append("\niOS check :").append(windows.isChecked());


                //Toast.makeText(Demo.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                text.setText(result);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            if (linux.isChecked()) {
                result.append("Android check : ").append(linux.isChecked());
            }
            if (macos.isChecked()) {
                result.append("Android check : ").append(linux.isChecked());
            }
            if (windows.isChecked()) {
                result.append("\niOS check :").append(windows.isChecked());
            }
            text.setText(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are doing something wrong in your layout xml? 
I copy pasted your code and used the following layout, everything worked fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Erfan Gholampour Its great. Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for.